# Why does Miller appear in different timings between series and book?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels, leviathan-wakes

**This questions contains spoilers for the book *Leviathan Wakes* and the first season of *The Expanse*.**

In the book Miller joins the crew of the *Rocinante* before they get to the *Anubis*, in the series he joins them afterwards.

Does anyone know why the show chose to do so?

Comment: I would like to edit this question for clarity, but I'm a bit confused. I haven't seen all the first season of the TV series yet, but I've read Leviathan Wakes and discussed it with friends who watched the entire season, and I'm under the impression that the Rocinante has not yet reached the Anubis as of the season finale. So it seems like you're asking about events that haven't yet occurred in the TV series.

Comment: I'm about to speak about episode 8, spoilers ofc:

In episode 8, amos is watching the logs in the stealth ship they found,almsot at minute 22:00 he says: "This ship is called the anyubis" the log shows: "Anubis" he just mispell ;P.

Comment: I'm reading it in my hand terminal (Thus I have some strange order in pages) but this should explain what im asking:

pages:
707->they on Lionel Polanski's room, with Miller.
710-> Juliette Mao in the shower, dead.
893->after Eros, Amos comes out of Rocinante: "Jesus cap'n you look like hell".
946 -> They arrive to the charted asteroid BA834024112

Now in series:
Chapter 8 chronologically:
They begin at BA834024112, without Miller. After they blow it they go to Eros and find miller in the hotel, Lionel polanski's and Mao in shower. Eros happens in 9-10 endseason chapters.

Answer (score 3):

They solve almost everything at chapter 8.
After a while I think they did it because Eros station with Miller and Holden is the part with most action, with the rest solved previously it was the perfect ending for a season. (specially when u can throw 2 episodes the same day).